# Acessing protected members of composition class

Tags: c++, composition, protected

I have the below class that has two custom objects as member variables.  I get errors with the bold section.  What is the proper way to access protected members of the composition classes? I get 'within this context' errors the f, gleft, and gright functions and when I try to resize u.

```
class C
{
protected:
    A x;
    B y;
    double a;
    double b;
    Eigen::MatrixXd u;

public:
    double f(double x)
    {
        return x;
    }
    double gleft(double tau)
    {
        return tau
    }
    double gright(double tau)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    FD_Euro_Put(): x(), y(), a(0), b(0){}
    FD_Euro_Put(char y1, double y2, double y3, double y4, double x2,
            double x3, double x4, double x5, double x6, double x7):
            x(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7)
    {
        double Xleft = x1*x2;
        double Xright = x1*x3;
        double Tauf = x1*x1;
        double NN = floor((x1/x2);
        a = x1*x2 - 0.5;
        b = x1*x2 + 0.5;

        pde = HeatPDE(y1, NN, Xleft, Xright, Tauf, Alpha); //begin problem area
        u.resize(pde.N+1, pde.M+1); 
        if(fdtype == 'f')
            u = pde.Forward_Euler(&f, &gleft, &gright);
        else if(fdtype == 'b')
            u = pde.Backward_Euler(&f, &gleft, &gright);
        else if(fdtype == 'c')
            u = pde.Crank_Nicolson(&f, &gleft, &gright); //end problem area
        else
            cout << "Incorrect choice for finite difference type!" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: `x1` seems to be missing in the constructor's signature... Also, you can't format a part of a code on Stack Overflow. Try to mark the section with code comments instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `protected` members of a class unless it explicitly lists you as a `friend` or you inherit from that class.

A hack would be to wrap that class in your own class which gives getters for those members.

But from a logical standpoint, if those members aren't `public`, you probably shouldn't need access to them anyway.

Comment: so would I just declare x and y as: friend classA x, friend classB y?

Comment: @riotburn look up friend declarations.

Comment: Ok I figured it out thanks! I have to add C as a public friend member to A and B.